# Is there a more elegant way to write this in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to append `'status'` to the dict value indexed by `'update_fields'` or add `['status']` as a value to kwargs indexed by `'update_fields'` if that key isn't present.

```
kwargs.setdefault('update_fields', kwargs.get('update_fields', []).append('status'))
```

It's either this or about 3 lines of code, surely python can do better than this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get` and `setdefault` are essentially two methods of doing the same thing; putting them together is repeating yourself.  The only difference between `get` and `setdefault` is that `setdefault` *sets* the value if the default doesn't exist.  After that, they are identical semantically.

So this part:

```
kwargs.get('update_fields', [])
```

..is redundant.  `setdefault` sets the default (and returns it, like `get`) if the dictionary doesn't have a value for that key yet, otherwise it just looks up the value associated with the key.

So all you need is:

```
kwargs.setdefault('update_fields', []).append('status')
```

Comment: Yea, I knew I must be doing something wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `kwargs.get()` bit, `setdefault` only sets the value if it's not already there, you can just write:

```
kwargs.setdefault('update_fields', []).append('status')
```